# How to get id of inserted record in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I want to get id of inserted record in zf2. I found solution using scope_identity in php. But how to use it in zend?

My code in indexcontroller is

```
<?php
    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new UserForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost())
        {       
            $form->setData($request->getPost());            
            if($form->isValid())
            {   
                $data=$form->getData();         
                $this->getUserTable()->insert($data);
            }
        }
    }
     public function getUserTable()
    {
     if(!$this->userTable)
     {        
      $this->userTable = new TableGateway('eo_user',$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
      );
     }   
     return $this->userTable;

    }
```

Schema for eo_user table is

```
eo_user

user_id  |  username  |  user_password  | user_email  | user_status
```

Here user_id is primary key with auto increment constraint.

What changes i need to do in order to find user_id of inserted record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$this->getUserTable()->getLastInsertValue();` to get last insert ID for the inserted record.

## UPDATE

```
$this->getUserTable()->insert($data);
$insertedId = $this->getUserTable()->getLastInsertValue();
echo $insertedId; // will get the latest id
```

Comment: should i REPLACE it with $this->getUserTable()->insert($data); or write AFTER it?

Comment: Need to write after insert.

Comment: But what if another insertion is made between these two by another user?

Comment: anyway your solution worked for my script,though its not proper solution. +1.thnx

Comment: @rack_nilesh, it will give the latest ID inserted for that instance and if any other user is inserting another record, then he/she will give another ID for that insert instance.

Comment: obviously it will. Is there any way to insert and get inserteId in single query,just like scope_idenity in php?

Comment: @rack_nilesh, if you will visit the method definition for `protected function executeInsert(Insert $insert)` present in `vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php`, you will find that last generated id is assigned to `$this->lastInsertValue = $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue()`. It assigns the last generated id for the current connection and `getLastInsertValue` method returns the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

After the insertion just call `mysql_insert_id()` function. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Edit: If this is too hard, then just do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` and you're there

Answer (score -1):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT max(id) FROM user';  

    $query = $this->getAdapter()->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    return $result[0]['max(id)'];
```

Comment: And what if meanwhile another user made another insertion?

Comment: i think it wont be effective way to write insert and select max queries  separately,as there is possibility to execute another insert query by another user.